# Stochastic Process | Doubt with an example

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm was reading an pdf about introduction to stochastic processes and the example say:
A coin it's tossed a few times. By each head the player win $1$ unit and by each tail the player loss $1$ unit.
So then in the example we have $n=6$ and $\omega = (h, h, t, t, t, t)$. This is

$X_1(\omega) = 1$

$X_2(\omega) = 2$

$X_3(\omega) = 1$

$X_4(\omega) = 0$

$X_5(\omega) = -1$

$X_6(\omega) = -2$

Next, the example fixs $t = 3$ for calcules the distribution of $X_3$ so the set of possibles states is:

[image]

So we have that:

$P{\{X_3 = -3\}} =\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{1}8$

$P{\{X_3 = -1\}} =3\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{3}8$

$P{\{X_3 = 1\}} =3\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{3}8$

$P{\{X_3 = 3\}} =\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{1}8$

Why $X_3 = -1$ and $X_3 = 1$ are multiplied by $3$?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax for the top part of your question.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: There's a typo in $X_6(\omega)$.  Its value should be $-2$ as $X_5(\omega) = -1$, and you state that one loses $1$ unit in case of tail.

Comment: You see that each of $1$'s and $-1$'s appears times in your tree diagram. Each occurrence accounts for $\frac{1}{8}$ probability, so the probability is $\frac{3}{8}$. Alternatively, note that in order to have $X_3=1$. So you must have two H's and one T: $$\mathbb{P}(X_3=1)=\mathbb{P}(\text{HHT})+\mathbb{P}(\text{HTH})+\mathbb{P}(\text{THH})=\frac{3}{8}.$$ This idea generalizes and can be dealt with binomial distribution.